# Dynamically accessing JSON objects in Groovy

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

Here is a query that I need to send to ElasticSearch :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all":{}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type":"number",
      "script": {
        "inline":"statusMap[status] || 0",
        "params": {
          "statusMap": {
            "CAN":5,
            "COM":4,
            "HLD":3,
            "PEN":2,
            "INP":1
          }
        }
      },
      "order":"desc"
    }
  }
}
```

Where `status` is a field of type string. The parameter `statusMap`'s value may differ from query to query, and I thought I could get around by just specifying the mapping value as is, since this is valid JavaScript anyway. Then I realized that the script is not JS, but Groovy.

The problem is that Groovy does not like the `statusMap[status]` at all. Is this JavaScript expression equivalent in Groovy? If not, what are the alternatives?

### Edit

The error message is

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "failed to run inline script [statusMap[status]] using lang [groovy]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason": "all shards failed",
      "phase": "query",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [
         {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "foo",
            "node": "8AcXwANfSd-HF-nyMXHDLw",
            "reason": {
               "type": "script_exception",
               "reason": "failed to run inline script [statusMap[status]] using lang [groovy]",
               "caused_by": {
                  "type": "missing_property_exception",
                  "reason": "No such property: status for class: 5ea995c6862849ebdbc5e3d4126d81302185a798"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status": 500
}
```

**Note:** changing `statusMap[status]` to `statusMap[doc.status.value]` yields a `null_pointer_exception` error message instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inline script needs to be like this instead:

```
    "inline":"statusMap[doc.status.value] ?: 0",
```

Also make sure that you have [enabled dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting).